# boolean is not recognized in jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a multiple choice trivia game, I'm passing a boolean value of true or false to a custom data attribute .. 'correct' in the various answer components.

When the answer is clicked on I'm running a check to see if the correct attribute has a value of true or false.

Here is one of the answers

```js
<Answer 
    onClick={this.answerClick}
    onMouseEnter={this.hoverEnter} 
    onMouseLeave={this.hoverLeave} 
    correct={this.state.correctAnswer.a1}>
    {this.state.answerSet.a1}
</Answer>
```

And here is the answer component itself

```js
const answer = (props) => (
    <div         
        className={classes.Answer}
        onMouseEnter={props.onMouseEnter} 
        onMouseLeave={props.onMouseLeave}
        onClick={props.onClick}
        data-correct={props.correct}>
        {props.children}
    </div>
)
```

So, on click I check to see if the data-correct attribute has a true or false value.

```js
answerClick(e) {
    console.log(e.target.dataset.correct)
    if(e.target.dataset.correct === true) {
        this.setState({ score: this.state.score +1, level: this.state.level +1})
        console.log('you have answered correctly')
    } else {
        this.setState({ level: this.state.level +1 })
        console.log('you have answered incorrectly')
    }
}
```

It only registers a false answer even when the correct one is selected.  I know that data-correct contains the value of true, because of my console log of the

```
console.log(e.target.dataset.correct)
```

Is there a jsx/react behavior taking place I'm not aware of?  Why would this only default to the else when the value of data-correct is true?  Any help would be great.

Comment: Please make sure the whole snippet can be tested so that you can get a full and accurate answer (Merge the 3 snippets so that a full functional component is present)

Comment: Noted, will make sure to do that in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOM attributes are read as strings, not booleans.

```
if(e.target.dataset.correct === 'true') {...}
```

Comment: Wow.. thank you,  it's interesting because I actually tried a comparison with '==',  you would think that would have taken care of the issue aswell?  

Either way you suggestion works.   Thanks for the help